# res.writeHead override not working

Tags: node.js, overriding

I'm trying to override the `res.writeHead` method in Node.js, though it's throwing an error. Here's the code:

```
const http = require('http');
http.createServer((req, res) => {
    const _writeHead = res.writeHead;
    res.writeHead = (...a) => {
        console.log('res.writeHead called!');
        _writeHead(...a);
    };
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    });
    res.end('Hello, world!');
}).listen(2020);
```

`res.writeHead called!` is logged and then I get a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusMessage' of undefined` when a client connects. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are calling `_writeHead`, the `this` object does not refer to `res`. It refers to the global context instead, preventing Node.js from functioning properly. Change `const _writeHead = res.writeHead;` to `const _writeHead = res.writeHead.bind(res);`.

Comment: FWIW using a non-arrow function and calling `_writeHead.apply(res, arguments)` would probably perform the best since the method is only called once. I'm not sure about the performance of `.bind()` vs `_writeHead.apply(res, ...a)` though, even in recent node versions (e.g. node v7.x) where `.bind()` is much faster.

Comment: @mscdex Just tried changing the arrow function to the old-style function. Didn't work. Same error.

Comment: To be clear, what I meant was something like this: `res.writeHead = function() { console.log('res.writeHead called!'); _writeHead.apply(res, arguments); };`. Also, having 3 explicit parameters and passing those directly would be even faster than `.apply()`: `res.writeHead = (code, msg, headers) => { /* ... */ _writeHead.call(res, code, msg, headers); };`.

Comment: @mscdex I would expect it to work, but it doesn't. Changed the `(req, res) =>` to a regular function and `res.writehead = (...a)` to a regular function. Still doesn't work.
Here, see for yourself: https://runkit.com/bdsomer/58e93bc7beced100147e42e5
https://runkit.io/bdsomer/58e93bc7beced100147e42e5/branches/master

Comment: FWIW I already tested it locally and it works on every supported node branch as well as master. Here is an online runnable version: http://rextester.com/NBB63833